# count on new event from 1

Tags: javascript, html, css

After hard work (I'm not advanced in js) I have some little pure js calendar. 
I'm pround to have it so far... but somethink I get stuck for days.

Here is my calendar:
https://jsfiddle.net/ck3nsemz/

I have the problem that my calendar events finally get sort that the multiday events are shown in the same hight therefore I fill days[x]["grid"] to keep the var.

if you watch my calendar you see that the "party" event value days[x]["grid"] is keeped but now the "new" event is counting to grid:3 but I want grid:1 for it.

I hope you understand my problem. "new" event should have grid:1!

```
.grid1, grid2, grid2 {
  position:relative;
}
.grid1 {
  top:0px;
}
.grid2 {
  top:20px;
}...
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. However, this seems like is a javascript problem, not CSS.

Comment: Would I be correct in summarizing that each event should get the first available slot (grid) on its start date and keep it afterwards. So on day 10 in your example party would still be on grid 2 and grid 1 would remain empty?

Comment: to Marcos Pérez Gude.... You are right. it have to do with my js... the css should only demonstrate what I want to do finally. First new event grid should have the right value 1.

Comment: to Me.Name In my example party on the 8th should by on grid 2 (that work!) and new event should float to grid 1 (that don't work!)

Answer (score 0):

For starters a friendly suggestion on filling of the objects. Instead of using sub arrays, you could define objects directly. For example:

```
days[0] = {
    start: "9-3",
    title: "Fritz",
    dur: 1
};
```

Or one step further, define an object and create the array from there

```
function Event(start,title, duration){
    this.start=start;
    this.title = title;
    this.dur = duration;
}

var days = [
    new Event('9-3','Fritz', 1),
    new Event('9-5', 'huhu', 3),
    new Event('9-5', 'dieter', 1),
    new Event('9-7', 'party', 8),
    new Event('9-8', 'new', 2),       
];
```

This makes the initializing a bit more concise and the fun part is, without changing anything else, your current code will still work when using the objects above (because javascript will translate the keyname to a propertyname on the objects)

One step further from there is to have the object definition parse the date and determine the end. (did that in the example). And buffer any other value that is needed.

Back to the problem at hand. Instead of adding the days (events) right away, the used grids have to be determined. One way is to get all days where grid is assigned first. To do that without resetting the days outside of scope, easiest is first to determine all events for that day and then get all events with a grid already assigned. javascript's filter function (for arrays) comes in handy for the task:

```
            var events = days.filter(function(e){ return e.start <= d && e.end >= d;}); //get all events for this day               
            if(events.length){
                var grid = 1,
                    gridstaken = events.filter(function(e){return e.grid}), //get all the taken grids
                    getfreegrid = gridstaken.length ?
                    function(){while(gridstaken.some(function(e){return e.grid===grid;})){grid++;}return grid++;} // if there are grids already taken, create a check function
                        :  function(){return grid++;}; //otherwise, simply increase grid
                //etc
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ck3nsemz/1/) / [FIDDLE2](https://jsfiddle.net/ck3nsemz/3/)

For the first filter an end property is used that was added to the example code, but can be obtained in your original code by comparing to start and increasing the start value as done there. In the example fiddle I took the liberty of moving a lot of logic to the Event object to show the possibilities of such an approach, but you can strip strip the needed parts to the current code. 
The second filter creates an array of events with an assigned grid. Finally the getfreegrid increases the current grid index as long as it's already used. A small addition is made that the searching is skipped if there are no assigned grids, but this is optional as well.

*edit*
As per the original example, the code above only sets the text of 'grid', but doesn't do any positioning. For an example including the positioning: [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/ck3nsemz/3/) This quick example uses an encapsulating div with position relative, sets the css of the `title` class to absolute and uses the style.top inside the adding to set the position. Perhaps not the most css way to go, but it works for the intended purpose.

As a small sidenote, when overlapping months the code above will only work if the previous month was already added.